# How do I flatten nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

My List is :

```
 [['kukatpally'], ['gachibowli'], ['Madhapur'], ['Chintal'],........]
```

I want to show like this

```
 ['kukatpally', 'gachibowli', 'Madhapur', 'Chintal',....]
```

so how to delete those '[' and ']' symbols..

Thanks in advance

Comment: then, please accept one that you think the most suitable answer. click on the tick next to the answer.

Comment: Please be aware that "_those symbols_" are not in the list. They just show up when you print a representation of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> ls = [['kukatpally'], ['gachibowli'], ['Madhapur'], ['Chintal']]
>>> l = [x[0] for x in ls]
>>> l
['kukatpally', 'gachibowli', 'Madhapur', 'Chintal']
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) :

```
import itertools

l = [['kukatpally', 'somethingelse'], ['gachibowli'], ['Madhapur'], ['Chintal']]

list(itertools.chain(*l))
>> ['kukatpally', 'somethingelse', 'gachibowli', 'Madhapur', 'Chintal']
```

Or [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
import itertools

l = [['kukatpally', 'somethingelse'], ['gachibowli'], ['Madhapur'], ['Chintal']]

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
>> ['kukatpally', 'somethingelse', 'gachibowli', 'Madhapur', 'Chintal']
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant that your sub lists might contain multiple items:

```
 >>> ls = [['kukatpally'], ['gachibowli'], ['Madhapur'], ['Chintal']]
 >>> new_list = [item for sublist in ls for item in sublist]
 >>> new_list
 ['kukatpally', 'gachibowli', 'Madhapur', 'Chintal']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [item[0] for item in old_list]
```